# Edit rejected as destructive because I edited in the answer that the OP led me to. Should I just post a new answer?

Tags: support

My edit was rejected as destructive because the answer led me to the correct implementation and I tried to edit in the correct version to give the original answerer the credit for leading me there. Should I instead of editing the sort-of right answer, just add in my answer that more completely answers the question and accept that?

The edit in question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6245153

Comment: The edit doesn't look as though it has been rejected yet. Though now you've brought it to attention of meta it may be. I'd tend to leave those for the post author to consider if they are online.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with how many rejections does it take to actually reject an edit.

Comment: The sad part is the guy is completely right, the thing he called a factory is *nearly* word for word what the mapper in my suggested edit became, but the one change (builderkey) dramatically changes the way the code works.

Comment: Takes 3 votes either way unless the post author unilaterally accepts/rejects or someone forces the issue by choosing "accept and edit" or "reject and edit"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are changing a lot of code, and those edits get rejected. Actually, you have an entirely different piece of code here. You can post that code as a new answer, and if the other answer helped you, you can always include credits in your answer and upvote the other answer.

You can also post a comment to the answer, to share your improvements if your code isn't too different from the other code.

Comment: I just feel bad since the only real difference between the two answers is that the answerer didn't understand it was a property of the item rather than the itemkey itself that determined which builder to map to.

Comment: @CBauer I expanded my answer. You can also post a comment to the answer.

Comment: Well the problem becomes that it's hard to say "oh, I'm keying onto an item property so that I don't create a separate builder for every itemkey in the system (millions)" in a meaningful way that the OP could rewrite his code. That's why I made an edit to encapsulate the scenario.

Comment: @CBauer You can put the updated code on Pastebin or GitHub Gist for example. But a code edit requires OP agreement so other users reject them.